# Flyway cannot connect to db after Heroku Postgres upgrade

Tags: postgresql, heroku, spring-boot, flyway

I am upgrading my heroku database from a hobby dev to Standard 0 (using the official instructions https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrade-with-pg-copy-default).

All went well, until I promoted the new database and restarted the app.  I then get the following error:

```
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
...
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
...
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "54.xxx.xx.xxx", user "u94bf9vxxxxxx", database "d2mqk0b6xxxxxx", SSL off
...
```

If I swap back to the old database again, everything works again.  The only thing that I am changing is the promoted database.

Is there a difference between connecting to hobby and standard databases that I need to be aware of?

The relevant part of my application.yml looks as follows:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
        url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL} 
        username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
        password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
flyway:
    enabled: true
    locations: classpath:db/migrations
```

Any suggestions on how I can debug this would be very welcome too.

Comment: Can't say I've used Heroku lately, but do you have access `pg_hba.conf` ? If so please provide it's contents which would certainly help isolate the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately not, this is hidden, and not editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you aren't connecting with SSL where it is required by Heroku PostgreSQL installs.

See Herokus [documentation on SSL for PostgreSQL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#external-connections-ingress).

See also Herokus [documentation for enabling SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java#connecting-to-a-database-remotely) on JDBC connections.

You will need to add something like `&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` to your JDBC URL.

Comment: Thanks - spot on.  P.S. I also got a response from Heroku support.  They suggested the same thing.  But also suggested upgrading my postgres JDBC driver to 9.4.x (I was using 9.0.x).  Doing this fixed it too (seems that the newer driver does the above behaviour by default).